# Export the same websocket connection to different files

Tags: node.js, websocket, server

To clarify, I've set up a websocket that sends back some data every few mins, and based on the data that is being sent back, I would like to run some routine on that data. And I'd like to continue running different routines using the same websocket at different times of the day. I need the streaming data, but I also need to have an event listener. My thought would be start up the websocket in a different file then export it to different files in the folder, but this doesn't work since a new websocket starts up. I can only have 1 websocket connection at a time.

For example:

**openConnection.js**

```
(() =>
{
    const url = "wss://stream.data";
    const ws = new WebSocket(url);

    ws.on('open', () =>
    {
        ws.send(`{"authorize"}`);
    });

    module.exports = ws;

})();
```

*then ->*

**someFunction.js**

```
const ws = require('./openConnection.js');

function foo ()
{
    // using the imported websocket
    ws.addEventListener('message', (data) =>
    {
        doSomething(data)
    });
}
```

Is there a way for me to use the same websocket connection throughout different files?

Comment: are you using express also?

Comment: FYI, there is ZERO reason to use an IIFE inside your module.  The module is already its own function scope so using an IIFE inside that function scope accomplishes nothing.  And, you're showing a mixing of CommonJS modules with ESM modules.  Pick `import` and `export` or `require()` and `module.exports`.  Don't mix unless you want to dive into the complex world of how to mix them successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you but when using socket.io and express you can simply pass io server to locals

here is the example

```
const server = http.createServer(app);
// Create HTTP server
const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
  },
}); // Create Socket.io server

app.locals.io = io; // Set io to global
```

in other files

```
const { io } = req.app.locals;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('New client connected');
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('Client disconnected');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CommonJS modules with `module.exports` and `require()`:

```
const url = "wss://stream.data";
const ws = new WebSocket(url);

ws.on('open', () =>
{
    ws.send(`{"authorize"}`);
});

module.exports.ws = ws;
```

and, to import that in a CommonJS module:

```
const { ws } = require('./openConnection.js');

function foo ()
{
    // using the imported websocket
    ws.addEventListener('message', (data) =>
    {
        doSomething(data)
    });
}
```

And, you can use that same `const { ws } = require('./openConnection.js');` from any other file because module handles are cached so the 2nd, 3rd, 4th times you `require()` it in, they just return the previous `module.exports` object.

Life will be simpler if you don't try to mix CommonJS modules and ESM modules.  So, `module.exports` is used with `require()` in a CommonJS module and `import` is used with `export` in an ESM module.

There are ways to load one type of module from the other, but life gets a lot more complicated as soon as you try to do that so it is best to stick with one module type if possible.